# import is not working with babel loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

this is my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
},
"license": "",
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "~6.4.5",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
  "webpack": "~1.12.12",
  "webpack-dev-server": "~1.14.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.4.9"
}
```

this is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname,'public'),
    entry: './entry.js',

    resolve: {
        root: [__dirname + "/public"]
    },

    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename:'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
    },

    module:{
        loaders:[
            { test: path.join(__dirname,'public'),loader:'babel'},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader:'style!css'}
        ]
    },

    devtool: '#inline-source-map'
}
```

this is my `entry.js`:

```
document.write('webpack!')

import 'angular';
```

this is the error i am getting:

> ERROR in ./public/entry.js Module parse failed:
>   /home/guy/itay/Develop/webpack-tut/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js!/home/guy/itay/Develop/webpack-tut/public/entry.js
>   Line 3: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

```
| document.write('webpack!');

| 

| import 'angular';

node version: 5.4.1,
npm version: 3.3.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that i used babel ^6.0.0 and i did not set the presets option in my loader like this:

```
query: {
  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
}
```

there is the link that helped me through that:
https://medium.com/@malyw/how-to-update-babel-5-x-6-x-d828c230ec53#.xn8bkagxz